# Japanese sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words

授業中に出題したレポート課題の提出内容で評価していきます. -> the teacher will evaluate based on the homework that i will upload during the lessons. Or homework that the teacher give during the lessons, and i upload it at home?

Comment: There is no word "upload" at all, in the given sentence. Please use a dictionary. Or otherwise rephrase the question so that it contains an actual question, instead of implied "what does this sentence mean?".

Comment: Ask your teacher.  You have the right to know exactly how your work is evaluated.

Comment: Please try to use specific question titles.  "japanese sentence" doesn't tell us anything at all about your question, except that it may contain a sentence.

Comment: The title is not specific enough, but OP clearly  i) asks about a specific sentence and ii) gives two possible interpretation she's come up with. Reading the translation I can assume that OP is  confused about what modifies what. I don't see how this question is put on hold.

Comment: Thankyou so much although it was put on hold, thanks for answering my questions all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although "Ask the teacher<sup>TM</sup>" is the best option (do so, really), I believe the following is the preferred interpretation of the given sentence.

> 授業中に出題したレポート課題の提出内容で評価していきます.

You'll be evaluated based on your 「提出内容」for the「[授業中に出題した]レポート課題」. So the homework will be given during the lessons, and whether you submit your assignment in-class or afterwards is not specified. In this case, 授業中に modifies the 出題-する, and 出題 is for giving questions (not for submission).

> レポート課題の授業中の提出内容で評価していきます

will correspond to your first interpretation.

> 授業中に出したレポート課題の提出内容で評価していきます

Here I changed the 出題する to 出す, which can be substituted for either 出題 or 提出 (submission). In this case it's more ambiguous whether 「授業中に出した」 modifies レポート課題 or 提出(内容). I think the former is still preferred because of the location (and context), and

> レポート課題の授業中に出した提出内容で評価していきます

is slightly unnatural but can only be understood with the latter (you submit during the lessons).

Another tricky, unlikely but not-impossible interpretation is

> 授業中に，出題したレポート課題の提出内容で評価していきます.

where 授業中に modifies 評価する: "I shall evaluate you during the classes, based on your submission for the assignments."

Comment: Thankyou so much!!! Yeah i asked my teacher and he will evaluate me based on report that i upload. And the limit time will be one week after the given time. Thanks for your help!! :)